# Web service architechture python to exchange json

Tags: python, json, apache, web-services, json-rpc

I need to design the architechture to run a real-time service in python.
The service needs to maintain a list of past information of all clients, so this will be the only process / thread.
The clients use web services requests to send JSON packets of data.

The question relates on how to design the architechture:

In the server:
- Apache web server
- XXX API (Json-rpc ?)
- UNIQUE Python process listening new JSON inputs.

So, my first approach would be to create a API that open a SOCKET with the Python process. Any example on how to build this architechture?

Comment: Can't imagine how you'd get anything approaching real-time with only a single thread. What happens when a second request comes in while you're still processing the first?

Comment: yeah, in fact I have 2 threads one for receiving JSON strings and other to process the data. How would you design the architechture then?